# Get convex hulls for all rasters in raster_columns

Tags: postgis, image

how to search the polygons of the images that I have in the Database?
I want execute this function ST_AsText(ST_ConvexHull(rast)) for every "r_table_name"

```
SELECT
    r_table_name
FROM
    raster_columns
```

[image: Image of the Bank]

```
SELECT
   ST_AsText(ST_ConvexHull(rast))
FROM
    NDVI_3_fev_18
```

[image: Polygons of the image]

Comment: your english is a little hard to understand ,) ...do you want the polygon that covers the whole raster image? could `SELECT ST_Envelope(rast) FROM ...` be what you are looking for?

Comment: @ThingumaBob I have seven raster in my bank and i want execute the same ST_ConvexHull for all rasters

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question to contain SQL as ASCII text in the body of the question. Screenshots are not legible on all devices, and are not searchable either.

Comment: I believe you are looking for ST_ConvexHull(ST_Union(rast)), but it is a bit hard to tell. What do you mean by bank?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I want execute this function ST_AsText(ST_ConvexHull(rast)) for every "r_table_name"

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça, you had sent me an answer that I thought was going to work, but it is not showing up any more. Could you send it to me again, please?

Comment: No problem. You will probably want to create a function if you are going to do that often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is harder than it seems, as you can't use table names directly as variables in pure SQL, so you can use the EXECUTE FORMAT construct, which allows you to construct dynamic SQL. Select the table and raster names from raster columns, and loop through, executing your ST_Convexhull(rast) query every time.

The [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) statement allows you to run a query once, and throw the results away. If you plan to do this often, create a function that does the same thing or convert the below into an insert into rather than a select, or something similar.

```
DO $BODY$ 
DECLARE rec record; 
            ans text; 
    BEGIN
      FOR rec IN SELECT r_raster_column AS rast, r_table_name AS tbl 
      FROM raster_columns LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Convexhull(%I)) FROM %I;', 
                        rec.rast, rec.tbl) INTO ans; 
        RAISE NOTICE '%', ans;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```